# How to select values by the count of a filed?

Tags: mysql, sql

How to select values in MySQL table by the count of a field in the same table ?

Example:

```
Table users has id, name, password, country
```

I want to select all ids of only top 3 countries with highest users count to look like this:

```
country, id
```

When I try this
`WHERE country IN (SELECT country FROM USERS GROUP BY country ORDER BY COUNT(id) DESC LIMIT 3)`

I get `This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`

Server version: 5.6.33-79.0 Percona Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join with a subquery that gets the top 3 countries.

```
SELECT u.country, u.id
FROM users AS u
JOIN (SELECT country
      FROM users
      GROUP BY country
      ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
      LIMIT 3) AS u1
ON u.country = u1.country
```

Practically any use of `WHERE column IN (SELECT ...)` can be changed to a `JOIN` like this, and in many cases the performance is better.

Answer (score 0):

> How to select values in MySQL table by the count of a field in the
>   same table?

Use the `GROUP BY field HAVING COUNT(*)=123` aggregation expression after the `WHERE` clause if there is.

Comment: how will HAVING COUNT(field)=123 will help here? I need to order the table by count first.

Comment: You asked two different questions. I answered the first of them.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
SELECT country, id 
FROM
      (
         SELECT country,count(Id) as [NumberofUsers]
         FROM USERS 
         GROUP BY country 
                           ) X
INNER JOIN USERS U ON X.Country=U.Country
ORDER BY X.[NumberofUsers] DESC LIMIT 3
```

Comment: That looks right, but you are assuming that country table has an id field, thus `COUNT(*)` is preferred.

Comment: the error is `This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`

Comment: @NagyWesley Updated my answer, do check and let me know if you get any issue.

Comment: The `ORDER BY NumberofUsers DESC LIMIT 3` should be inside the select statement to work, anyway I've accepted  @Barmar answer... thanks for the help